# GET Parameter with forward slash in PHP / htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Lately i'm having some trouble with htaccess and PHP. 
I have a running code that removes the ".php" from the web address just with the .htacess file, turning:

This address

```
http://localhost/dashboard.php
```

Into

```
http://localhost/dashboard
```

Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But now I'm trying to pass some GET parameters through forward slash. Like this:

Turn this:

```
http://localhost/dashboard.php?id=20
```

Into this:

```
http://localhost/dashboard/20
```

I've already tried this code, but doesn't work (error 500):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(\d*)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2 [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: URL rewriting does not work in this way... you cannot change what's appearing the address bar (eg. the version with ".php" will always exist UNLESS you remove the extension physically from the file!)

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error is most probably the result an internal rewrite loop since the condition that checks that the request + `.php` extension (ie. `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php`) maps to a file is not necessarily the same as the URL-path you are rewriting to (ie. `/$1.php?id=$2`). See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following ServerFault question that discusses this in detail: https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?(\d+)?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

This handles both scenarios:

- `/dashboard` is internally rewritten to `/dashboard.php?id=`
- `/dashboard/20` is internally rewritten to `/dashboard.php?id=20`

Having made the `RewriteRule` *pattern* more restrictive, the check that tests whether the request maps to a file would seem to be superfluous, since the *pattern* is unlikely to match a real file. Besides, any real file + `.php` is unlikely to be a file as well anyway - so both checks are not required.

There is no need to backslash escape the literal dot in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* (ie. `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php`) since this is an "ordinary" string, not a regex, consequently the dot has no special meaning here.

MultiViews needs to be disabled for these directives to function as intended. (This may already be disabled on your server.)

---

*Aside:*

> I have a running code that removes the ".php" from the web address just with the .htacess file

Whilst this is commonly written (incorrectly) in this way, that's not what those directives do. (The `.php` extension has presumably already been removed in your HTML source.) In fact, those directives do the complete opposite... they add back the `.php` file extension to the requested (extensionless) URL to internally rewrite the request back to the underlying filesystem path.

(You could use `.htaccess` to *remove* the `.php` extension, for the benefit of SEO (only). But that requires a very different rule - an external redirect.)